# $_GET['_escaped_fragment_'] not returning anything

Tags: php, ajax

I'm following a tutorial on [html snapshot](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/html-snapshot) for how to return a snapshot and the first thing I'm testing is if `$_GET['_escaped_fragment_']` returns anything and it doesn't, the code I have is this:

```
<? 
  $escaped_fragment = $_GET['_escaped_fragment_'];

  if(isset($escaped_fragment)){ ?>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      console.log("helloo")
    })
    </script>
<? } ?>
```

Normally I would get a `helloo` in console, but I don't. What could I be doing wrong?

**Edit:** I'm opening the `URL` as `domain.com/?_escaped_fragment_`

Comment: First of all, it's a good idea not to access super globals directly. Instead use `filter_input()`, e.g. `filter_input(INPUT_GET, '_escaped_fragment_');`

Comment: does domain.com/?_escaped_fragment_=1 makes a difference?

Comment: @DorMoshkovitz sadly no. I think it's the `_` that's causing the problem. If I change `$escaped_fragment` to `$_GET['test']` it works.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is maybe that you have some sort of URL handling in e.g. a `.htaccess` file, that isn't processing this particular parameter very well.